# Calculate value to Percentage, and base other values based on this value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of several DateTimes.
The DateTime is actually a String in HH:mm:ss format which i convert to DateTime.

From this list i retrieve the largest value (in minutes)

I calculate the total Minutes like the following:

```
//t is a DateTime
Double totalMin = TimeSpan.Parse(t.ToString()).TotalMinutes;
```

The largest value (in minutes) should be used as the "100%" value.
I already have calculated the largest value of the list.

Meaning all the other values (also in minutes) in the list will be calculate based on this value.
The other lower values have to scale on this max value in other words.

This will be used in a bar chart. So the largest value will take the most space followed by the lower values.

How exactly can i do this?

Thanks PeterP.

Comment: `t1.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes` would be the right way

Comment: percentage = totalMin / 100 * someMin

Comment: In case if start point is 12AM ))

Comment: @V4Vendetta Could you elaborate whats wrong with my code for the min? The DateTime is actually a String with hh:mm:ss format which i convert to a DateTime.

Comment: @PeterP Why would you do a `ToString()` on a string then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know how to calculate a percentage? Divide the current by the max and multiply it with 100. Then you can format the percentage like you want (like "20%", "20.2%", ...).

```
Double max = 200d;
Double current = 23d;

Double percent = current / max * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Timespan is the difference, in some unit of time, between two DateTime's.  You're parsing a DateTime.  You're gonna get a FormatException:

```
Double UhOh = TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()).TotalMinutes;
```

results in:

```
System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Now to answer your question, you're going to need another piece of data:  Another DateTime in order to find the difference, in minutes, between those two points.

Let's assume you want to use:

```
DateTime.Now
```

This would work:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2012,4,19,0,0,0);
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - t;
Double mins = ts.TotalMinutes;
```

Hope that helps. (:

Comment: Since they are not originally DateTime objecs but rather Strings in hh:mm:ss format (filled up by using Stopwatch) would i not be better off keeping it as a string and using timespan to retrieve the amount of minutes? Thanks.

Comment: OH, okay!  I just saw your comment and thought it was a DateTime:

    //t is a DateTime (:

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing `Timespan` and converting `DateTime` to a string which is not really required.

Do you mean something like this

```
List<DateTime> lstdt = new List<DateTime>() {
                new DateTime(2010,5,5,1,10,0),
                new DateTime(2011,5,5,2,10,0),
                new DateTime(2010,8,5,1,10,0),
                new DateTime(2010,5,5,1,10,0),
                new DateTime(2011,11,5,1,10,0),
                new DateTime(2010,12,5,1,10,0),
            };            

double maxval = lstdt.Max(c => c.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes);
List<double> lstpercent = lstdt.Select(d1 => d1.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes/maxval *100.00).ToList<double>();
```